# Edit: Namespaces, and Exception Handling

Tags: python

In my introduction to computer science class we are learning about namespaces. And I understand the concept as in when importing a module like math, then we are importing a namespace and the, the class attributes under that namespace, but executing the process is very confusing to me. Here is one of the questions that I have no idea how to begin executing:

Write a function, `name_add(a,b)`, that uses exception handling (just a simple `try/except` statement) to add two objects, a and b, and return the result. If the user calls the function with any types for which the `+ operator` is not defined, the function should print a message stating that the addition operator is undefined between `type(a)` and `type(b)` (whatever those types are)......l

If someone could explain step by step what this function should look like or what they are asking in beginners terms, I would greatly appreciate it because I am not really understanding this at all or the relation it has to namespaces.

Comment: I don't see a relation to namespaces, it seems pretty straight forward .

Comment: I didn't know Python had "namespaces".

Comment: @squiguy everything in python is in a namespace of some kind.

Comment: @squiguy: Start the python interpreter and type `import this`. Look at the last line...

Comment: @squiguy, I think the questioner refers to namespaces in a more general sense, like sets of names that can be accessed from a given scope.

Comment: `val = name_add(a,b)` assign the returned value to a global variable.

Comment: @RolandSmith A module? I thought the question was referring to scoping issues.

Comment: @squiguy: Just try it... It's called the Zen of Python. It has to do with your comment, not with the question per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to catch the TypeError exception. This is the answer to the question:

```
def name_add(a,b):
    try:
        return a+b
    except TypeError:
        print 'The + operator is not defined for a and b'
        return None
```

As Lattyware commented, catching the exception and just printing a message is *not* a good practice. You should either:

- Solve the exception in the function so that the function can go on and produce a sensible result (Which is not possible in this case).
- Let the program catch the exception at a higher level.

Look at this fragment of one of my programs. This is the top level function:

```
def main(argv):
    """Main program for the nc2pdf utility.

    :argv: command line arguments
    """
    if len(argv) == 1: # No filenames given, only the name of the script
        binary = os.path.basename(argv[0])
        print __proginfo__
        print "Usage: {} [file ...]".format(binary)
        print
        sys.exit(0)
    del argv[0]
    for fn in argv: # Loop over all the files
        try:
            ofn = outname(fn) # outname can raise ValueError...
            with open(fn, 'r') as inf: # Open can raise IOError
                rd = inf.read()
        except ValueError:
            fns = "Cannot construct output filename. Skipping file '{}'."
            print fns.format(fn)
            continue
        except IOError:
            print "Cannot open the file '{}'. Skipping it.".format(fn)
            continue
        ... # do something with the file's data
```

In this case, the exception can be handled by skipping (not processing) one of the files named on the command line and moving on to the next file. Not handling the exception here would crash the program, even though other files might still be processed. A filename can be misspelled, or the process may not have access permission to the file. These things happen and should be handled gracefully.

Comment: Returning `None` when something fails is a really bad idea. re-raising the exception with `raise` would be best.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> 
>>> def bar():
...     global foo
...     foo = 2
... 
>>> bar()
>>> foo
2
```

If you're not trying to modify the global variable, simply use:

```
# Inside yourfuncs.py
def adder(a, b):
    """
    Returns the sum of a and b, or raises an exception.
    """
    try:
        return a + b
    except TypeError:
        print 'Oops'
        raise
```

Then:

```
>>> import yourfuncs
>>> x = adder(1, 2)
>>> x
3
>>> addr({}, 1)
Oops
# traceback omitted
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'
```

Note that I didn't stop the error from being propagated. Don't return the sum when it works, and then an error string when it doesn't. That's bad design. If you want to raise your own exception, that's a fine idea.

Comment: I think he is talking about a return value, not modifying a global

Comment: @cmd - The title says, `a Python function that modifies a variable defined outside of the function`

Comment: @orokusaki Yes, but the question goes on to completely change what is being asked, as far as I can see.

Comment: @orokusaki dont judge a question by its title?

Answer (score 2):

To modify a variable declared outside of a function, you have to use the `global` keyword in the function:

```
a = 1
def mod(b):
    global a
    a = b

mod(2)
print a
#prints 2
```

**Note:** this applies for immutable types (strings, numbers, booleans, tuples), but for lists:

```
a = [1,2]
def mod(b):
    a[0] = b

mod(2)
print a
#prints [2,2]
```

For the problem you mention in the body of your question (which is somehow totally different than the title) I recommend the answer of Ronald Smith.

Comment: I think he is talking about a return value, not modifying a global

Comment: My answer fits the title, but yes, the body of the question is a whole different story.